# XSLT : How to copy nodes referenced by id

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input :

## input.xml

```
<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="about" kind="page">
    <title>About This Document</title>
    <innerpage refid="t1">Item1</innerpage>
    <innerpage refid="t2">Item2</innerpage>
</compounddef> 

<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="t1" kind="page">
   <title>This is item 1</title>
</compounddef> 

<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="t2" kind="page">
   <title>This is item 2</title>
</compounddef>
```

I'm trying to nest pages references by inner page inside the parent page. I.e. expected output should be :

## expected_output.xml

```
<compounddef xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="about" kind="page">
    <title>About This Document</title>
    <innerpage refid="t1">Item1</innerpage>
    <innerpage refid="t2">Item2</innerpage>

    <sect1 id=t1>
        <title>This is item 1</title>
    </sect1>

    <sect1 id=t2>
        <title>This is item 2</title>
    </sect1>

</compounddef>
```

In a given page can be 0 to many inner pages. 
Currently, I was able to nest all the inner pages in all not inner pages. with the following xslt.

## transform.xslt

```
    <xsl:key name="inner-page-ref" match="compounddef[@kind='page']/innerpage" use="@refid"/>
    <!-- remove unmatched -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>


   <xsl:template match="/doxygen">
        <doxygen version="{@version}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "compounddef[@kind='page' and not(key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"/> 
        </doxygen>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef/innerpage" mode="list"> 
        <innerpage> 
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </innerpage>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef/innerpage" mode="body"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "/doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page' and key('inner-page-ref', @id)]"/> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page'and not(key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"> 
            <compounddef id="{@id}" kind="{@kind}">
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="list" select = "innerpage"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="body" select = "innerpage"/>
           </compounddef>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doxygen/compounddef[@kind='page'and (key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"> 

            <xsl:message> innerpage <xsl:value-of select ="@refid"/> </xsl:message>
            <sect1 id="{@id}">
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
            </sect1>
    </xsl:template>
```

I need to create a list of pages that are subpage for a specific page any apply only them. But can't find a way yet. 
Any hint will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ilya.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how the "inner-page-ref" key is defined please? Thank you!

Comment: Added, sorry forgot to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a key `<xsl:key name="inner-ref" match="compounddef" use="@id"/>` and then you process/apply-templates to `select="key('inner-ref', innerpage/@hrefid)"` as that is the "list" (node-set in XSLT 1, sequence in XSLT 2) of referenced `compounddef` elements by the `innerpage` elements.

A more complete example would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:key name="inner-ref" match="compounddef" use="@id"/>
   <xsl:key name="inner-page-ref" match="compounddef[@kind='page']/innerpage" use="@refid"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/doxygen">
        <doxygen version="{@version}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select = "compounddef[@kind='page' and not(key('inner-page-ref', @id))]"/> 
        </doxygen>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="compounddef">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('inner-ref', innerpage/@refid)" mode="sect"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="compounddef" mode="sect">
            <sect1 id="{@id}">
                <title><xsl:value-of select="title"/></title>
            </sect1>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7n5

Output there is

```
<doxygen version="">
  <compounddef id="about" kind="page" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <title>About This Document</title>
    <innerpage refid="t1">Item1</innerpage>
    <innerpage refid="t2">Item2</innerpage>
    <sect1 id="t1">
      <title>This is item 1</title>
    </sect1>
    <sect1 id="t2">
      <title>This is item 2</title>
    </sect1>
  </compounddef>
</doxygen>
```

Comment: Sorry, not clear to me. I'm not xslt expert thinking C here. I  need a list that will have a key as a combination of parent id i.e. id_about + t1, id_about + t2. After that inside page processing (id_about), I need to find all pages that match id_about + wildcard.

Comment: Start using and thinking in XPath and XSLT terms. A key declares your intent to find nodes by the `use` expression so the XSLT processor will index the nodes given in the `match` by the `use` expression and a call to the `key` function then returns a node-set of nodes with the key values passed in/selected in the second argument of the `key` function call. I have added a complete stylesheet that uses the key to follow/process the referenced nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, now I will try to understand how :)  Next stage i will need to transform all internal items,i.e. if the parent of sect1 node parent is page keep as is but if the parent is an innerpage change to sect2 and so on ...   My C head say pass parameter to the template indicating who is the parent, but I suspect there are better ways to do it.